# Laravel php artisan doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, autoload, vendor

I'm trying to use php artisan in my laravel directory but it gives the following warning

```
PHP Warning:  require(/home/mahmoud/Desktop/Learning/laravel/blog/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/mahmoud/Desktop/Learning/laravel/blog/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/mahmoud/Desktop/Learning/laravel/blog/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/mahmoud/Desktop/Learning/laravel/blog/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17
```

Comment: How did you install laravel?

Comment: composer global require "laravel/installer"
and placed $HOME/.composer/vendor/bin in my path by editing ./bashrc

and laravel command works

Comment: `composer install` is pending @MahmoudYoussef

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try:

```
cd /home/mahmoud/Desktop/Learning/laravel/blog
composer install
```

you should see the vendor folder under blog directory, if you still have the problem execute `composer du`

Comment: it was my bad I had some problems with php mbstring but your command created the vendor file

Answer (score 1):

Try `composer update` i think this will fix your issue

Answer (score 1):

Run composer with `--no-scripts`

```
composer update --no-scripts
```

Go to Command Prompt set path to your project, then type this command:

```
composer install
```

It will automatically install all dependencies in `vendor/`.

Comment: it didn't work, I don't have a vendor directory at all in my project

Comment: It did not work for me too