# PHP Artisan get ErrorException: Array offset null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

Can someone help me? When I try any Artisan command, always I get this error in some project I've downloaded:

```php
In ServiceProvider.php line 84
 Trying to access array offset on value of type null
```

At first, I get a similar error like this: [Laravel php artisan doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44478486/laravel-php-artisan-doesnt-work).

Comment: Please, also add the code on the `ServiceProvider.php` file.